# Passing Form Data Between Components & Vue Routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-component

I am trying to create a step-by-step form using Components & Routing. If there is a better or easier approach to do this, please feel free to suggest, since I am new to Vue.js.

I have a  and 3 templates.

```
<template id="step-1">
  <h1>Welcome to Form</h1>
</template>

<template id="step-2">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" v-model="name" />

  <br />
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email" />
</template>

<template id="step-3">
  <p>Review:</p>

  <!-- Display Step 2 Form Values -->
  {{ name }}
  {{ email }}

  <button>Submit</button>
</template>
```

What I want to do is, display the input values on #step-3, and on a button click, submit the form via an ajax call.

You can view the Fiddle from here: https://jsfiddle.net/j7mwc9wk/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is for all three components use the same data object. For the purposes of this bit of code it can be a simple javascript object. A bit more sophisticated approach is to use Vuex an official Vue data store.
You could also have these three components have the same parent in which case name and email would be properties of parent data method and therefore accessible to all children. I don't know how this would work with Vue router but it should be fine.